TypeError: Object of type CartItem is not JSON serializable
I've a view class which stores the list of cartItem object in the session:
View class:
class AddCart(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        prod_id = self.request.POST.get('prod-id')
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=prod_id)
        quantity = int(self.request.POST.get('quantity'))
        cart = self.request.session.get('CART_ID')

        if cart is None:
            cart = Cart(self.request)

        cartItem = CartItem(product_id=prod_id, name=product.name, quantity=quantity, image=product.image,
                            totalprice=float(product.price) * quantity, unitprice=product.price)
        cart.update(cartItem)
        print("Cart updated in View")
        # del self.request.session[settings.CART_ID]
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Added to cart'})

Cart class looks like:
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
    # def __init__(self):
        self.session = request.session
        cart_id = settings.CART_ID
        cart = request.session.get(cart_id)
        self.cart = cart if cart else []
        # self.cart = []

    def update(self, cartItem):
        cartList = self.cart
        print("cart list",cartList, "cartItem:",cartItem)
        found = False
        totalquantity = 0
        for cart in cartList:
            if cart.product_id == cartItem.product_id:
                found = True
                totalquantity = cart.quantity + cartItem.quantity
                cartList.remove(cart)
        if not found:
            cartList.append(cartItem)
        else:
            newItem = CartItem(product_id=cartItem.product_id,name=cartItem.name,image=cartItem.image,quantity=totalquantity,unitprice=cartItem.unitprice,totalprice=totalquantity*cartItem.unitprice)
            cartList.append(newItem)
        self.cart = cartList
        self.session[settings.CART_ID] = cartList

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cart)

CartItem class looks like:
class CartItem(object):
    def __init__(self, product_id, name, image, quantity, unitprice, totalprice):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.unitprice = unitprice
        self.totalprice = totalprice

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_id}-{self.name}-{self.image}-{self.quantity}-{self.unitprice}-{self.totalprice}"

But when post method of AddCart view called get below error:
Last few lines of stack Trace:
Internal Server Error: /add-cart/
...
  File "C:\Users\enarban\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\enarban\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type CartItem is not JSON serializable
[11/Aug/2024 15:32:44] "POST /add-cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 122549


Where is the issue? Please help me to find the problem.

Please show full traceback.

Hello @raphael,
I found the problem.  Before saving to session object needs to be in json format.
Python obj__dic__ will give a json object. Then we can store in session.
Thanks.

Before saving to session, object needs to be in json format.
        cartList.append(newItem.__dict__)
        request.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = cartList
        request.session.modified = True


Thanks

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
